# sizeof(pointer_to_a_function) vs sizeof (function_name)

Tags: c, function, function-pointers, implicit-conversion, sizeof

[image]

Here is the program as text:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int x){
    return x+1;
}

int main() {
    int (*p)(int) = f;

    printf( "%d\n", sizeof(p) );
    printf( "%d\n", sizeof(f) );
}
```

The image relates to the C code and my question is very specific to C only.

Here `f` is a name of a function and `p` is a pointer to the function `f`.

Since `p` is ultimately an address so depending on the size of the address bus the output of `sizeof(p)` is coming out to be true and that's totally fine.

Here `f` is also pointing to the function `f`. So ultimately `f` is also an address.

My main question is that why the output of `sizeof(f)` is not 8, why it is 1 and how it is 1?

Comment: Do not post _pictures_ of code.  Post the code at text with appropriate markdown.

Comment: Aside: you should be using `%zu` format specifier with a `size_t` operand. The code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: _"Here `f` is also pointing to the function `f`. So ultimately `f` is also an address."_ -- This is not correct: `f` is a function designator which may be converted to a pointer.

Comment: @adabsurdum Yes, "f is a function designator" is _the_ cause of OP's misunderstanding shown by "Here f is also pointing to the function f".

Comment: Downvoted for a picture of code. I wanted to confirm this result in my compiler, but couldn't. I respectfully suggest to not leave your questions unattended after posting to be able to correct issues like those.

Comment: Indeed both GCC and Clang print 8 and 1 here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6dYGYvbvP

Answer (score 9):

It is not allowed to take the size of a function.  Section 6.5.3.4 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the `sizeof` operator states:

> The `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression that has
> function type or an incomplete type, to the parenthesized name of such
> a type, or to an expression that designates a bit-field member. The
> `_Alignof` operator shall not be applied to a function type or an
> incomplete type.

This is considered a *constraint violation*, which triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Also, the proper format specifier for printing an expression of type `size_t`, which is the type given by the `sizeof` operator, is `%zu`, not `%d`.  Using the wrong format specifier also triggers undefined behavior.  In this particular case you got a value that made sense for the first case, but there's no guarantee of that.

Answer (score 3):

For starters you have to use conversion specification `%zu` to output a value of an expression with the sizeof `operator`

```
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( p ) );
```

Otherwise in general such a call with using the conversion specification `%d` instead of `%zu` can invoke undefined behavior.

Pointer is a complete type. So its size is known.

> Here f is also pointing to the function f. So ultimately f is also an
> address.

`f` is not a pointer. It is a function name. According to the C Standard you may not apply the `sizeof` operator to functions.  A function can be implicitly converted to a pointer to the function. However if it would be allowed to apply the `sizeof` operator to a function nevertheless neither implicit coversion is performed for expressions used in the `sizeof` operator. For example arrays are also can be implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements. However if an array is used in the `sizeof` operator such implicit conversion is not performed.

Consider the following code snippet

```
int a[10];

printf( "sizeof( a ) = %zu\n", sizeof( a ) );

int *p = a;

printf( "sizeof( p ) = %zu\n", sizeof( p ) );
```

Its output might look like

```
sizeof( a ) = 40
sizeof( p ) = 8
```